# top: 50% does not working when set to position relative

Tags: html, css, css-position

The top position of the **frame1** remain the same even already set top: 50%. The containing block is body tag. Not understand why it is not working?

```html
<html lang="en">
  <body>        
    <div class="frame1">
      <div class="frame">
        <div class="center">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS file**:

```css
.frame1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: orangered;
    border: 2px solid blueviolet;
}
```

Comment: 50% of 0 is 0...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is is top:50% in css not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765402/why-is-is-top50-in-css-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Position relative means, that the position is relative to where the item would be in the document by default.

Hence `top: 50%; left: 50%;` doesn't do anything. Because it's 50 percent something undefined.

Comment: This is wrong. 50% means half the parent width/height. It has nothing to do with the item to be positioned itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your 50% setting for `top` doesn't have a reference height: The parent element in your case is `body`, with no defined height. So the browser doesn't "know" of *what*  to calculate the 50%. If you add `height: 100%` to `body` and `html` (i.e. parent of `body`), your setting will have an effect:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.frame1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: orangered;
  border: 2px solid blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div class="frame1">
    <div class="frame">
      <div class="center">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```